# Как сверстать фон шапки?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Надо сверстать фон шапки как у этого сайта psdmania.ru. Чтобы было во весь экран.

Comment: а как сверстать горизонтальную линию под шапкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имели ввиду самую верхнюю полосу, то вот

```
header {
  background: url("http://psdmania.ru/templates/PSDmania8/img/userbar-tx.gif"); 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  height: 58px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Бекграунд сохраните себе на комп

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в header

```
{border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```